# Error adding a pointcloud to a viewer

Tags: point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I encounter an error while running this code ..

```
access violation in reading memory location

pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);  //fill the cloud. 
cloud-> width = 100;  
cloud->height = 10;
cloud->is_dense = false;
cloud->points.resize(cloud->width*cloud->height);  // generate the data 
//double temp_x , temp_y , temp_z;
for (size_t i = 0; i!=cloud->points.size(); i++)  { 
    cloud->points[i].x = 1024*rand()/(RAND_MAX + 1.0f); 
    cloud->points[i].y = 1024*rand()/(RAND_MAX + 1.0f);
    cloud->points[i].z = 1024*rand()/(RAND_MAX + 1.0f); 
}  
pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer viewer;     
viewer.addPointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>(cloud);
while(!viewer.wasStopped()){  
    viewer.spinOnce();  
}  
system("PAUSE");
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think "cloud->height=10" means that it's organised point cloud type.
And you should try to set cloud->height=1.
good luck!